# preg_match substring only if is valid

Tags: php, preg-match, substring, extract

I need to extract a substring from an email subject only if valid. The valid substring is like:

`ab-2011-0023ad` or `ac-2011-0023ad.r1`, only two dashes are allowed, number of letters after second dash varies, but only alphanumeric with one dot or without dot.

I wrote this one, but if I put after second dash an illegal character, the regexp returns partial substring not empty

```
/([a-z0-9]{0,3}[-]\d{4}[-][a-z0-9.]+)\S/i
```

i.e.: `"this is an email with ab-2011-0023:ad document"`, I expect from regexp to return empty array not `[0] => ab-2011-0023`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reg exp is not correct. 
1. Never use one literal in symbolic class like this [-]. You should escape it -, but nod add to symbolic class.
2. [a-z0-9.]+ this piece matches with string "..............". So, it's not correct.
3. In the end you use as delimiter \S (matches everything except the whitespaces).

My advice is to use smth like this (if your reg exp engine supports Negative Lookbehind)

```
/[a-z\d]{0,3}\-\d{4}\-(?:[a-z\d]+|(?<!\.)\.)+\s/i
```

[example](http://regex101.com/r/nB3yD1/1)

Comment: Your example working fine, but you have an error in your answer. The correct one is:
([a-z\d]{0,3}\-\d{4}\-(?:[a-z\d]+|(?<!\.)\.)+)\s

Comment: "Error" - you mean lack of preserving parentheses? If you want only check string (match) no need to use them. In demo on regex101 it used to highlight matches.
Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping (`.` matches any character), and force to match the full string (with `$` inicating end, `^` indicating beginning):

```
/^[a-z0-9]{0,3}[\-]\d{4}[\-][a-z0-9\.]+$/i
```

Example:

```
$subject = "ac-2011-0023ad.r1";
$subject2 = "ab-2011-0023:ad";

if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{0,3}[\-]\d{4}[\-][a-z0-9\.]+$/i",$subject,$match)) {
  echo "Found : ".$match[0]."\n";
}

if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{0,3}[\-]\d{4}[\-][a-z0-9\.]+$/i",$subject2,$match)) {
  echo "Found : ".$match[0]."\n";
}
```

Comment: There're no need to escape `-` if it is the first or last character in a character class nor the dot in a chracter class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add space around your regex:

```
/(?:\s|)([a-z0-9]{0,3}[-]\d{4}[-][a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?)(?:\s|)/i
```

Comment: @user3917799: Could you explain in which way it doesn't work?

Comment: I've tested here: http://regex101.com/r/mK0wU8/1, it's not what I've asked for in my question. Thanks anyway, I appreciate any help.